# Executing external python code without changing original variables

Tags: python

When I execute external python code using the exec() method:

```
i = 0
exec("i = 99\nprint(i)")
print(i)
```

*Output:*
99
99

The code I'm executing changes the variable **i** in my original program. What alternative way of executing external python code can I use to hinder this? Consider that the code I'm executing is given to me as a string, and I have no control over it or its variable names.

*Desired Output when executing the same code:*
99
0

Comment: this is incredibly insecure, you should never blindly execute code in this way, not least of which among reasons, because of the behaviour you've just discovered

Comment: You can set the globals and locals to empty: `exec("yourcode", {}, {})`. Or, wrap the `exec`  to a function so that the `exec` will not modify the global variable. BTW, It is not recommended to use `exec` in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I recognize the insecurity of this approach, [HALF9000 provided an approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036337/executing-external-python-code-without-changing-original-variables#comment128995514_73036337) in the comments that suits my needs. Setting global and local variables to empty in the exec method solves my problem:

```
i = 0
exec("i = 99\nprint(i)",{},{})
print(i)
```

*Output:*
99
0

Answer (score 0):

You code:

```
i = 0       #i=0
exec("i = 99\nprint(i)")     #i=99
print(i)                     #i=99

Output:
99
99
```

Execute line by line:

New Code:

```
exec("i = 99\nprint(i)")            #i=99
i = 0                               #i=0
print(i)                            #i=0  

Output:
99
0
```

Explanation:
Python executes code line by line, in your code, you declare 0 then update value 99 then print 2 times if you want to desire output then you can initialize 99 and print it first then after that you can initialize 0.